# a class to programm matryoshka dolls

Tags: java, class, model

I want to implement matryoshka dolls.
If you open one doll, there will be a smaller one inside until a massive doll that does not contain any another doll.

My try:

```
public static class Puppe{

    int massive;
    Puppe contains; 

    public static boolean massiveOrNot(Puppe doll) {
        if(doll.massive==0) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    public static Puppe exchangeDoll(Puppe doll) {

        Puppe newDoll=new Puppe();
        doll=newDoll;
        return doll;
    }

}
```

I´m completly new to classes.
How can I save dolls within other dolls and for example count how many dolls are inside of one doll?

Best regards
sop

Comment: Massive? Do you mean tiny?

Comment: You will probably need a constructor to set `massive`. Also `massive` might be better as `boolean isMassive;`, or is massive a badly named variable to hold the order of the dolls i.e. The inner most is 0 the one outside that 1 and so on...? It's not very clear what `exchangeDoll` is trying to achieve, assigning to `doll` wont do anything as its an object reference scoped to the `exchangeDoll` function. What should that function do?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes it is better as a boolean. I take one doll and need to read from it, if it is massive or not. If it is massive, than I get another doll. So I check it again if it is massive....until I find the massive one. Means the one that can´t be open up.

Answer (score 0):

First thing get rid of static for now, you will need more of this objects.
Then you have to think about is your object going to contain.

```
public class Puppe{
  Puppe container;
  public boolean isContaining() {
     if(container != null) return true;
     return false;
  }
  public void setDoll(Puppe smallerOne) {
       container = smallerOne;
  }
  public Puppe getDoll() {
       if(container != null)
        return container;
       return nullptr;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The object new Puppe is supposed to contain another new Puppe, except if it is massive.